# Unmarshalling JSON list using Apache Camel Rest DSL with servlet component

Tags: java, json, jackson, apache-camel

I have a little Java project providing a simple Apache Camel web service consumer based on Rest DSL. I'm getting a bug while unmarshalling a JSON object to a POJO containing a List.

Here's some code:

```
public class CustomRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        restConfiguration()
                .component("servlet")
                .enableCORS(true)
                .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.auto)
                .dataFormatProperty("prettyPrint", "true");
        rest("/")
                .post("call")
                .consumes("application/json")
                .produces("text/plain")
                .type(SamplePayload.class)
                .to("stream:out");
    }
}
```

Here's the SamplePayload.java

```
import java.util.List;

public class SamplePayload {

    private List<Product> products;
    private String id;
    private String name;

    public List<Product> getProducts() {
        return products;
    }

    public void setProducts(List<Product> products) {

        this.products = products;
    }

    public void addProduct(Product product) {
        this.getProducts().add(product);
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Product.java looks like this:

```
public class Product {

    private String name;
    private Double price;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(Double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

When I run this on Glassfish and use Postman to send some sample JSON like this

```
{"products":[{"name":"1. Product","price":99.95},{"name":"5. Product","price":29.99}],"id":"1234567","name":"my sample payload"}
```

I'll get the following error:

> org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during
>   execution on the exchange: Exchange[ID-XPS13-33852-1475945281007-0-2]
>         at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapCamelExecutionException(ObjectHelper.java:1706)
>         at
>
> org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultExchange.setException(DefaultExchange.java:349)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.UnmarshalProcessor.process(UnmarshalProcessor.java:84)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.binding.RestBindingProcessor.process(RestBindingProcessor.java:188)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:468)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197)
>     at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:121)   at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83)     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:109)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:91)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.http.common.CamelServlet.service(CamelServlet.java:143)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
>     at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedMethod.getParameterType(I)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JavaType;
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jaxb.JaxbAnnotationIntrospector._fullDeserializationType(JaxbAnnotationIntrospector.java:1593)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jaxb.JaxbAnnotationIntrospector._findContentAdapter(JaxbAnnotationIntrospector.java:1557)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jaxb.JaxbAnnotationIntrospector.findDeserializationContentConverter(JaxbAnnotationIntrospector.java:1233)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotationIntrospectorPair.findDeserializationContentConverter(AnnotationIntrospectorPair.java:560)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.findConvertingContentDeserializer(StdDeserializer.java:906)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.createContextual(CollectionDeserializer.java:156)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.createContextual(CollectionDeserializer.java:25)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleSecondaryContextualization(DeserializationContext.java:653)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findContextualValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:408)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.findDeserializer(StdDeserializer.java:881)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.resolve(BeanDeserializerBase.java:436)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:293)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:242)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:143)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findRootValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:439)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._findRootDeserializer(ObjectMapper.java:3666)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3558)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2648)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.component.jackson.JacksonDataFormat.unmarshal(JacksonDataFormat.java:172)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.UnmarshalProcessor.process(UnmarshalProcessor.java:69)
>     ... 39 more

I've tested several things including:

- remove the List --> unmarshalling works --> doesn't help, I need the list
- create a separate sample project using Jetty --> works like a charm! --> but I need it running on Glassfish.

Does anyone have a clue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: See here https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-jaxrs-providers/issues/74

Comment: ok. so you mean there's a version conflict? But this doesn't solve my problem. I've already tested with different version - no success.